# default drop down option in dynamically loaded pages

Tags: javascript, php, interrupt

I am creating an update interface for a mysql database. On clicking update button, it calls update.js

I have a drop down box named geography to select a country from. I am using a get_options() function to populate it dynamically. (This js calls a php script to connect to mysql table of countries) 
Then, I use `xmlHTTPRequest` method to fill my update interface by the existing values from the database.
`update.js` looks like:

```
get_options();
//alert("geog is " + jsonData.geography);
$("#geography").val(jsonData.geography);
```

I want the country fetched from the database to be the default option in the drop down. But the first country in the list of countries is always set as default. But if I uncomment the alert mentioned above, then the country from database is correctly set as default. I don't know how a delay or interrupt like alert helps here. 
But in my final interface, I don't need these alerts. So how can I achieve default drop down options without interrupts like alert ?
Also please explain how alert is helping me here.

Comment: Are you updating the dropdown menu in the ajax callback function? Sounds to me like the alert is giving the ajax function time to return a value but as xmlhttprequest should be doing this asynchronously the update should be from within a callback

Comment: I am also populating my drop down using another xmlHTTPRequest.

Comment: fetch all countries(as you have done) ,,, and then fetch the country of current ITEM (or whatever), than match their ID's or NAMES and mark SELECTED for the same values ... 
The current country of the ITEM will be selected and the rest are populated